# Acumatica - Display row numbers

Tags: acumatica

Is there a way to display row numbers in Acumatica grid? You could display LineID; however, when you sort your columns the LineID's will of course become scrambled.

Thanks,

Comment: you want to add line numbering on existing screen or on your own?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two possible cases: 
1. you need to add row numbers to existing screen
2. you need to add row numbers to your screen

For case 1 consider that you want to add row numbers to page po301000, tab Document details. The grid in tab Document details is binded to DataMember Transactions as you can see on screenshot fragment:

[image: DataMember Transactions]

Second part of puzzle is graph, which you need to extend. As you can see from screenshot you need to extend PX.Objects.PO.POOrderEntry:
[image: graph for extension]

Third part that you'll need is extending of POLine. You can achieve it with following sample of code:

```
public class POLineExt : PXCacheExtension<POLine>
{
    public abstract class rowNumber : IBqlField
    {

    }

    [PXInt]
    public int RowNumber { get; set; }
}
```

and extend graph like this:

```
public class POOrderEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<POOrderEntry>
{
    public PXSelect<POLine, Where<POLine.orderType, Equal<Current<POOrder.orderType>>, And<POLine.orderNbr, Equal<Optional<POOrder.orderNbr>>>>, OrderBy<Asc<POLine.orderType, Asc<POLine.orderNbr, Asc<POLine.lineNbr>>>>> Transactions;

    protected IEnumerable transactions()
    {
        var result = Base.Transactions.Select();
        int rowNumber = 1;
        foreach (PXResult<POLine> lineBoxed in result)
        {
            var line = lineBoxed.GetItem<POLine>();
            var lineExt = line.GetExtension<POLineExt>();
            lineExt.RowNumber = rowNumber;
            rowNumber++;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

And the final part, you'll need to add your customized column on your page:

```
 <px:PXGridLevel DataMember="Transactions">
                            <Columns>
                                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="RowNumber" Width="80px"></px:PXGridColumn>
```

After all of this I've seen the following on mine page purchase orders:

[image]

Second case is very similar to first described here, just with difference that you don't need to extend anything.

Comment: Nice, with virtual fields also. Thanks